# Output the published date / last modified date of specific page

Tags: pages, date, publish

I am trying to output the published date and last modified date of specific pages on a exclusive portal for certain users. Right now I can only find something similar for posts or within the specific page.

Is there anyway to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Postdata for all post types (*`post`, `page` and any custom post type*) are stored in exactly the same way and is returned in exactly the same way. The `WP_Post` are build exactly the same each time.

The use of template tags are also not different in any way. In short, what works for normal posts must work for pages and must work for a custom post type

You must be doing something wrong because displaying post date and modified date for posts and pages is exactly the same